# How should I use redux with nested subcomponents that won't be reused?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on a component that has many subcomponents, some of which are nested five deep.  I'm interested in using redux for the advantage of having a single source of truth in a common state atom.

What I'm not understanding is the smart/dumb component recommendation and putting the provider above the main component and passing everything down via props.  If I do this then I'd need to pass props down all the way to the fifth nested item so it can make a callback to dispatch an action or to look at some state that only it needs and not its parents.  I understand this is for code reuse, but the subcomponents will never be used outside of the main component.  What is the recommended solution here?  Still use props?

Note:  the author of this library requested we ask questions on StackOverflow.  I'm mentioning this because SO seems to flag "best practice" questions as too vague.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle global state data into deeply nested components in Redux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299460/how-to-handle-global-state-data-into-deeply-nested-components-in-redux)

Comment: This remains your choice - take a look at https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/668585589609005056 (got it back from my twitter feed, thought it was relevant at the time ;-) )

Answer (score 12):

While the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299460/how-to-handle-global-state-data-into-deeply-nested-components-in-redux) matt clemens posted does cover this at a high level, but I'll try to go into more depth here.

**You can use `connect()` at any level**. Doing so makes the component **smart**, since it knows where its `props` come from. A **dumb** component just has `props`, and they could come from anywhere. A smart component is *coupled* to redux; a dumb component is not.

[There are differing opinions on this approach](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/419), but it is supported and valid.

Where to draw this line is entirely up to you, but let's look at an example. You have some chat client with a standard sidebar component, a message window, and the entry field for sending new messages.

```
+---------+--------------------------+
|         |                          |
|Sidebar  |  Messages window         |
|         |                          |
|         |                          |
|         |                          |
|         |                          |
|         +--------------------------+
|         |  New Message Entry     **|
|         |                          |
+---------+--------------------------+
```

The parent of all of these would use `connect()` to get the data from redux and feed it into these components via props. Now imagine that those two asterisks besides `new message entry` open up a settings panel (ignore the stupid placement, this is an example). Does it really make sense for `new message entry` to pass those props through? No, it doesn't.

To solve this you could create a special "container", lets call it `SettingsContainer` that used `connect()` to get its props and all it did was pass them down to `SettingsPopup`. `SettingsPopup` would not know about redux, and could still be tested/styled/reused normally, and the new message entry would only need to know about `SettingsContainer`, not any of its dependencies.

This approach scales well, but it has two penalties. First, the smart "wrapper" components like `SettingsContainer` have to be consumed by otherwise dumb components. This complicates the testing of the new message entry component. Second, the top-level component no longer exposes the entire graph of data dependencies, which makes things harder to reason about without delving deep into the component hierarchy.

These tradeoffs can be worth it, but you should be aware of them.

Comment: _This complicates the testing of the new message entry component._ This can be solved by injecting the "smart" components (a.k.a. containers) into the "dumb" components.

Comment: @LarsNyström I am not sure how that would work. A demo would be much appreciated (probably also a valuable answer)

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way of doing it, but I wrote about one idea on how it's possible in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311081/react-dependency-injection-or-similar/38010717#38010717

Answer (score 5):

You can use the newer React feature of [context](https://medium.com/@skwee357/the-land-of-undocumented-react-js-the-context-99b3f931ff73#.pqwz0cert), via using 'react-redux''s component [Provider](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store). Using Provider will abstract away some of the implementation details of context, makes your markup quite expressive imho.

You basically setup a mini-global property, that all sub-components, dumb or smart can reference:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'; //Special Redux component to help
import {reducers} from './reducers.js';


var DeepDumbChild = (props, context) => (
    <div>
        <pre>
            {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
        </pre>
    </div>
)


class SmartChild extends React.Component {
    render() {
        /* Use the global-like context */
        let data = this.context.store.getState();
        return (
            <div>
                <DeepDumbChild data={data}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
SmartChild.contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropsTypes.object /* required */
}

/* No messy props :) */
var App = () => (<div>
    <SmartChild/>
</div>);


render(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: context with <Provider> seems to be an awesome idea for  passing the redux store down to nested components . But why is there a big warning issued  on the fb page against it ? **If you have to use context, use it sparingly.** _confused_

Comment: The way I think about it, is its the _one_ "global variable" you get to use in your application state. Like all globals, useful but dangerous. If you go by the name, use it for things that only change the "context", if I have a complex components `<TeamRoster />`, and `<TeamStats />`, I might wrap them in `<Provider store={redTeam} />`, and `<Provider store={blueTeam} />`.

Comment: Is it possible that your SmartChild component can call action methods using dispatch?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** If you want to try the approach below, have a look at https://github.com/artsy/react-redux-controller, which I recently published.

I think the best way to go is to map selectors to `context` at the root (container) component, rather than having a bunch of containers or using `connect` everywhere. I've done this in my own project and it's working beautifully. It adds a new pattern of annotating selectors with the `PropType`s they produce. That let me use `childContextTypes` to allow all descendants to retain the same protections they have with `propTypes`. This is an advantage over [Ashley Coolman's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426180/807674) of passing down a big untyped object being passed down. I'm hoping to have time in the next couple days to factor it into its own library and publish.

In the meantime, I'd suggest [making components smart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34320909/807674), using `connect` liberally, rather than [Tyrsius's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426073/807674) of creating a whole bunch of containers, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Its [not my idea](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.olvmdi3fy), it comes from Dan Abramov (creator of redux)