# dispatch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to add the [redux-file-upload](https://github.com/blueberryapps/redux-file-upload) library into a redux application.

In my component I am just adding the component exported from the lib.

I can see that the store is referred via [context](https://github.com/blueberryapps/redux-file-upload/blob/master/src/FileUpload.react.js#L27) inside the library.

Sample code is as below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FileUpload } from 'redux-file-upload';

class Upload extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FileUpload
        allowedFileTypes={['jpg', 'pdf']}
        dropzoneId="fileUpload"
        url="/api/path/action"
      >
        <button> Drag or click here
        </button>
      </FileUpload>
    );
  }
}

export default Upload;
```

However I get error as

`Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function`

Any ideas? Guess it is some mistake in importing the component.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function

I have come across this error many times for different reasons. I can't dive into the source code of that library, but it looks like that library is not able to get `dispatch` function from the redux `store`. Have you tried connecting your component to the redux `store` using `connect()` method? It's a long shot. Thought, it might work! Let me know...

**UPDATE**
I'm throwing related links here, hoping that you'd find the relevant piece of code.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/108

[React with Redux? What about the 'context' issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428355/react-with-redux-what-about-the-context-issue)

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/108

Comment: Yup I have tried connecting to the store from parent component.. Ideally it must work coz the context type set in the library.. And it should get access to store via the provider

Comment: Actually @gaearon replied to this and that's the idea used in the library https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/108#issuecomment-140778557

Comment: @anoop Yes, I noticed that! And maybe I'm not fit to help you any further. Please update your question if you find the answer. That'll be very helpful to understand the behaviour of `context`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13316755)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Sorry for that! But one can write only so many characters in comment section. Hence the answer. Shall I delete it?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13316755)

Comment: @lokusking Right! I'll edit the answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need import 'redux-form' , your code should be like this...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FileUpload } from 'redux-file-upload';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class UploadForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FileUpload
        allowedFileTypes={['jpg', 'pdf']}
        dropzoneId="fileUpload"
        url="/api/path/action"
      >
        <button> Drag or click here
        </button>
      </FileUpload>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'upload-form',
  fields: ['fileUpload']
})(UploadForm);
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation as to why this should be done/works?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this may not  work because the library mentioned is using context instead of connected components

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a middleware with you store, like redux-thunk/redux-promise?

The library you are using [*requires* it](https://github.com/blueberryapps/redux-file-upload#install):

> "Please note - a middleware that passes dispatch to actions, e.g.
>   redux-thunk, redux-promise-middleware, is required for this package to
>   work properly."

So if you are using react-redux and the Provider yuo can do the following:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise'

const storeWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);
```

Comment: Could you update your question with how you are doing so?

Comment: I think my question has enough details and more details can be found at this github issue https://github.com/blueberryapps/redux-file-upload/issues/11